# Disable link if current image is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I disable the thumbnail link if the current image is begin shown?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".image").click(function() {
            var image = $(this).attr("rel");
            $('#image').hide();
            $('#image').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');

            return false;
        });
    });
```

```
<a href="#" rel="<%=  image.photo.url(:small) %>" class="image">
    <%= image_tag(image.photo.url(:thumb)) if image.photo %>
</a>
```

Comment: Give us more code.. A fiddle would be great! -- And only as an advance, I'm thinking in some class="disable" to the link when the click action is trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".image").click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr("rel");

    if($('img', '#image').attr('src') == image) return false;

    $('#image').hide();
    $('#image').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#image').html('<img src="' + image + '"/>');

    return false;
});
```